# New line (in the code) after <li> element breaking layout

Tags: php, html, css

Weirdly, I've never come across this issue before, but I've just started making a site and the top navigation isn't playing nicely.

I want a small amount of white space between each menu item, but when I have new lines between my `<li>` elements and my `<a>` elements in my IDE (Netbeans), the white space disappears, yet it looks fine if I have `<li><a></a></li>` all on the same line. I was always under the impression html ignored white space in the code.

I've checked for any weird characters causing problems in other text editors and can't find anything.

Here's the code...

Like this the menu looks correct but code looks ugly (I know it looks fine when it's this simple, but I'm going be adding more complexity in which makes it look awful all on one line):

```
            <ul id="menu">
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li class="active"><a href="<?php echo site_url("tracklist"); ?>">Track List</a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php echo site_url("stats"); ?>">Stats</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Stats</a></li>
             </ul>
```

Produces:
[image: correct]

Like this the menu looks wrong but code looks fine:

```
            <ul id="menu">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="<?php echo site_url("tracklist"); ?>">Track List</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="<?php echo site_url("stats"); ?>">Stats</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Stats</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

Produces:
[wrong http://img708.imageshack.us/img708/6628/screenshot20100618at000.png](http://img708.imageshack.us/img708/6628/screenshot20100618at000.png)

I'm sure it's something simple I'm doing wrong... but can someone shed some light on this for me?

Sorry for the lengthy post (my first on stackoverflow).

---

Edit - Full CSS and HTML:

```
body {
   /* font-family: 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif; */
   font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', Helvetica, sans-serif;
   /* font-family: 'Copperplate', 'Copperplate Gothic Light', sans-serif; */
}

a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#container{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 800px;
}

#content {
    margin-top: 50px;
}

#header {
    background-image: url("../images/absolute_radio_logo.png");
    border-bottom: solid 1px #777777;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 800px;
    height: 86px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}

#menu {
    float: right;
}

#menu li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #932996;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #932996;
}

#menu li:hover {
    border-bottom: solid 3px #FF0000;
}

#menu li.active {
    background-color: #58065e;
}
```

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Radio - Statistics</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/resources/css/style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">

            <div id="header">
                <ul id="menu">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="http://localhost/tracklist">Track List</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="http://localhost/stats">Stats</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Stats</a>
                </li>
    </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="content">
            <!-- content -->
                   Elapsed Time: 0.0033 - Memory Used: 0.4MB
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show us the html that is rendered when the formatting is neat, but the display is off?

Comment: I've just added images so you can see, as I'm working on it locally for now.

Comment: What browser and docType are you using? I am unable to reproduce the error in IE and FF on strict.

Comment: I'm using strict, and get the same on the latest versions of Firefox, Chrome, Safari and Opera (all on the Mac).

Comment: If it is displaying wrong in the WYSIWYG of the Netbeans IDE...then thats just the way it is...sorry.  However if this is happening in a certain browser, please tell us the browser as well as the surrounding HTML. Thanks

Comment: Try adding the newlines in an editor other than netbeans and see if that helps. If that doesn't work then can you do a view source on the page with the newline and post that to see if there are any weird characters being added.

Comment: No, I wasn't using the WYSIWYG of Netbeans, just pure code. It happened in the latest versions of Firefox, Chrome, Safari and Opera (Mac).

and there was no weird characters in the view source.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you get the same effect if you put spaces instead of newlines? (Not that this is something you want to do — just to confirm that there isn't something even weirder going on here.)

Comment: Just tried it, and yep spaces have the same effect as newlines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to be totally fine with the CSS you supplied, so I'm guessing there must be some other rule affecting your links. Could you please supply us with a live preview or the full stylesheet?

Edit:

Seems to be an issue with how "display: inline" collapses the elements contents, though I couldn't find any proof of that. Change

```
#menu li {
  display: inline;
}
```

to

```
#menu li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

or add a margin to it:

```
#menu li {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

To fix the alignment of the text, I'll go ahead and recommend you float the `li`s. Someone please correct me if this is a horrible idea. Add

```
#menu {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#menu li {
  float: left;
}
```

to your existing rules.

Comment: I've added the full css and html. Could it really be a css issue if just removing lines from the html code fixes it?

Comment: Changing it to `display: inline-block;` worked, I'm still baffled that a new line in the html requires a css change though...

Comment: Hmm, maybe this isn't the correct solution. IE7 doesn't support inline-block. There must be some way of doing this with `display: inline`. I'm sure I've seen it loads of times.

Comment: As stated above: keep it at `display: inline` and add a margin.

Comment: Adding a right margin almost does it... but you can see the link isn't in the centre: http://img121.imageshack.us/img121/66/screenshot20100618at015.png

`text-align: center;` doesn't seem to work?

I'm sure I've never had this much trouble creating a menu in my life before :p bizarre!

Comment: 3 hours later and I've got a working menu, yay! haha

Thanks for your help =)

Answer (score 0):

Just as a guess try setting the line-height for the li & a tags to 1em or even 0

```
#menu li, #menu a {
  line-height: 1em;
}
```

Comment: That didn't seem to do anything unfortunately :(

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, those two screenshots appear to be swapped around, the first has gaps between the links, caused by the white-space in the second code snippet.

This new white-space-collapse property may be able to help.

> `#menu li{white-space-collapse:discard}`
>
> via: http://safalra.com/web-design/html-and-css/white-space-property/

If that doesn't work, the next option is to set the `<a>` tags to block level elements and the `<li>` tags to inline.

```
#menu li{display:inline}
#menu li a{
  display:inline-block
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #932996;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #932996;
}
#menu li a:hover{
  border-bottom: solid 3px #FF0000;
}
#menu li.active a {
  background-color: #58065e;
}
```

Comment: The OP wants a gap between the links. The OP is saying that the gap doesn't appear in the second code snippet.

Comment: Yeah, I want the gap between. Putting the code on new lines is *removing* the white space (which I don't want).

Comment: My apologies.

#menu li{margin-right:5px}
#menu li:last-child{margin-right:0}

Comment: Adding a right margin almost does it... but you can see the link isn't in the centre: http://img121.imageshack.us/img121/66/screenshot20100618at015.png

`text-align: center;` doesn't seem to work?

I'm sure I've never had this much trouble creating a menu in my life before :p bizarre!

Answer (score 0):

You must set  `overflow: hidden` on the parent box, then set `position: relative` on the `<li>`:

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 25px;
  margin: 5px 0;
  overflow: hidden
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 19px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative
}

ul li::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 400%;
  height: 1px;
  background: #f3f3f3;
  bottom: 0;
  right: -250px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

so it seems the targeted answer's have all been provided, so I'd just like to add that as a rule of thumb I always use [normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) which is a css library that ensures normal

you can download it or use npm install normalize.css